# Get URL from all images in a post

Tags: posts, images

so i made a blog and a few posts, but i would like to get all the URLs from the images in a post, and then later put them in a carousel. But right now it doesnt find any images and says No images found every single time.
What am i doing wrong?

This code is in my single.php:

```
<?php                   
    $attimages = get_attached_media('image', $post->ID);
    if($attimages){
        foreach ($attimages as $image) {
            echo wp_get_attachment_url($image->ID).'<br>';
        }
    } else{
          echo 'No images found';
    }           
   

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably can't find any attached images because those images are not considered 'attached' or have been attached to another post before.

With this script you can search directly in `the_content()` for all the attached images and then create another list with only the `<img>` tags cleaned from the rest of the text.

```
$post_content = $post->post_content;
$search_pattern = '/<img.*?src="(.*?)"/i';

// Run preg_match_all to grab all the images and save the results in $embedded_images
preg_match_all( $search_pattern, $post_content, $embedded_images );

// Check to see if we have at least 1 image
$embedded_images_count = count( $embedded_images[0] );

if ( $embedded_images_count > 0 ) {
     // Now here you would do whatever you need to do with the images
     // For this example the images are just displayed
     for ( $i=0; $i < $embedded_images_count ; $i++ ) {
          echo $embedded_images[0][$i].'<br>';
     };
};
```